# Pass parameters to Timer Task (Java)

Tags: java, timer

I have a timer task in a loop. I want to pass into the time task which number it is in a loop.

Is that possible?

My code:

```
...
int i = 0;
while (i < array.size){
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new RegrowCornAnimate(), 0, 1000);
i++
}
...

class RegrowCornAnimate extends TimerTask {
     public void run() {
//Do stuff
   }
}
```

How can I change it so I can use `i` in the TimerTask class? -as in each TimerTask will know which `i` it was created under/in/from.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
class RegrowCornAnimate extends TimerTask {

    private final int serial;


    RegrowCornAnimate ( int serial )
    {
      this.serial = serial;
    }

    public void run() {
      //Do stuff
    }
}

...
int i = 0;
while (i < array.size){
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new RegrowCornAnimate( i ), 0, 1000);
    i++;
}
...
```

Comment: Precisely what I wanted thanks, I learn't this less than two weeks ago, how could I forget OOP!

Comment: @Steven. No problem. Practice makes perfect!

Answer (score 5):

Give the `RegrowCornAnimate` class a constructor that takes an `int` and store that in a field. Pass `i` to the constructor when you create it.

Answer (score 4):

Create a constructor in `RegrowCornAnimate` taking the parameters you'd like to use, then store them as members inside your class.

When `RegrowCornAnimate.run` is called read the values.

Answer (score -1):

Please see an example at 
http://www.roseindia.net/java/task-scheduling.shtml. This example prints a number with each run.

Comment: You should consider fleshing out your answer, preferably to including relevant content from the linked site.  Link only answers can be interpreted as spam / not an answer (as they are very susceptible to link-rot).