# Passing Parameters through Timers in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to pass a parameter through my timer. I have seen this post, [Pass parameters to Timer Task (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498691/pass-parameters-to-timer-task-java), but it seems to use a different timer that I am using. I have seen some other post too, but none seem to work. Here is my code.

```
public static Timer sendObjects = new Timer();
    public static TimerTask sendTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            //This is where I would use the variable I pass through
    };
```

I want to pass through a String array to this timer task. Similar to the way you would do it with a method. How could I do this, and what would I use to run this?

Comment: And what is the problem you are facing? I think you should include more context.

Comment: I want to know how I can pass a parameter though this timer.

Comment: Timer or TimerTask?

Comment: Timer Task sorry

Comment: Extend the timer task as described in the link you provide, and include a constructor that accepts `String[]`, what's the problem?

Comment: Can you provide an example? Sorry I am knew to Timers and Java in general. If I could see how it is done it would be great for reference. I have tried to follow the link but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: It's literally the same code, just replace `int` with `String[]`.

Comment: But he uses the class and doesn't define a Timer Task. Would you just mind just giving me an example please?

Comment: Please read about inheritance in java. Inheritance defines the "is-a" relationship, in that link, the author writes `RegrowCornAnimate extends TimerTask`, meaning RegrowCornAnimate  is a TimerTask.

Comment: Wow that helped a lot! Thanks! I think I can get this to work now.

Comment: Welcome. It is the same as when you have `class Animal` and write `Dog extends Animal`, meaning `Dog` is an `Animal`.